# Groovy precedence issue

Tags: groovy

I'm implementing a weighted lottery in groovy.  It allows some participants to have a better chance at winning than others (basically exactly like the NBA draft).  It works by tossing each participant into an array N times where N is the number of chances you have to win.  It then picks a random index from that array.

Like a good little coder, I wrote a test.  It picks a winner from the group 100 times and outputs how many times each participant was picked.  The expectation being that it would fall roughly in line with how many times they should be picked (based on their number of chances).  The results were...off.

I narrowed the issue down to a single line that, if split into 2 separate statements, works perfectly.  A slimmed down version of the routine is below.  The "bad" version is active and the "good version" is commented out

```
def randomInRange(int min, int max) { 
       Random rand = new Random()
       rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min
}

def bob = [name:'bob', timesPicked:0]
def joe = [name:'joe', timesPicked:0]
def don = [name:'don', timesPicked:0]

def chanceWheel = []

//don should get picked a lot more
2.times{chanceWheel << bob}
2.times{chanceWheel << joe}
6.times{chanceWheel << don}

//pick somebody at random from the chance wheel 
100.times{
    //this will produce timesPicked counts that do NOT sum to 100 and usually under-represents don
    chanceWheel[randomInRange(0,9)].timesPicked++

    //splitting the logic into 2 lines will always have the correct sum of timesPicked with roughly the right distribution of winners
    //def picked = chanceWheel[randomInRange(0,9)] 
    //picked.timesPicked++
}

println bob
println joe
println don
```

My question is what is wrong with the one liner version?  My guess is that its an order of execution issue but I cannot for the life of my figure out where its going off the rails.

Comment: `chanceWheel[randomInRange(0,9)].timesPicked++` is `chanceWheel[randomInRange(0,9)].timesPicked = chanceWheel[randomInRange(0,9)].timesPicked + 1` which calls  randomRange twice in contrast to the working example where it is called once and assigned to a variable. ;)

Comment: Ahhh.  So essentially the issue is that a participant's timesPicked is not being incremented.  It is being overwritten by another random participant's timesPicked (after it is incremented).  I tested this by dumping the current pick counts inside the loop and can see this is the behavior that is occurring.  Thank you kind sir

Comment: You can also move the `randomInRange()` out of the `[]` into a var to "fix" it.  Yet this looks more like an error in the code generated here.  Or is this java behaviour?

Comment: The minimalistic version that fails: `def c=0; def r={ c++ }; m=[[x:0],[x:0]]; m[r()].x++; assert m[0].x==1`

Comment: @dmahapatro you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
chanceWheel[randomInRange(0,9)].timesPicked++
```

is

```
chanceWheel[randomInRange(0,9)].timesPicked = 
    chanceWheel[randomInRange(0,9)].timesPicked + 1
```

which calls `randomRange()` twice in contrast to the working example where it is called once and assigned to a variable.